# how to select mutilindex row?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Let's say i have a multiindex dataframe like below.

```
                      ROW_ID    HADM_ID ICUSTAY_ID
SUBJECT_ID  CHARTTIME           
23  2157-10-21 12:05:00 1   124321  234044.0
    2157-10-21 14:00:00 30  124321  234044.0
    2157-10-21 19:00:00 77  124321  234044.0
    2157-10-22 00:00:00 148 124321  234044.0
    2157-10-22 04:00:00 197 124321  234044.0
    2157-10-22 08:00:00 226 124321  234044.0
    2157-10-22 16:00:00 320 124321  234044.0
34  2191-02-23 08:00:00 367 144319  290505.0
    2191-02-23 12:00:00 450 144319  290505.0
    2191-02-23 15:00:00 476 144319  290505.0
    2191-02-23 20:00:00 511 144319  290505.0
    2191-02-24 00:00:00 538 144319  290505.0
    2191-02-24 04:00:00 567 144319  290505.0
    2191-02-24 07:00:00 608 144319  290505.0
    2191-02-24 12:00:00 648 144319  290505.0
36  2134-05-12 07:00:00 685 165660  241249.0
    2134-05-12 12:00:00 787 165660  241249.0
    2134-05-12 16:00:00 855 165660  241249.0
    2134-05-12 20:00:00 924 165660  241249.0
    2134-05-13 00:00:00 988 165660  241249.0
```

SUBJECT_ID and CHARTTIME are the multiindex. now i want to get the row of every SUBJECT_ID  with every first CHARTTIME.so the expected output is:

```
                      ROW_ID    HADM_ID ICUSTAY_ID
SUBJECT_ID  CHARTTIME  
23  2157-10-21 12:05:00 1   124321  234044.0
34  2191-02-23 08:00:00 367 144319  290505.0
36  2134-05-12 07:00:00 685 165660  241249.0
```

I have tried to use iloc and xs, but it not work. any help will appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to groupby on index, you must pass the level param instead of the by param

```
df = df.reset_index('CHARTTIME')
df = df.groupby(level=['SUBJECT_ID']).first().set_index('CHARTTIME', append=True)
```

Comment: Use `df.reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=[0]).first().set_index('b',append=True)`